# highstocks series zones color not showing up

Tags: highcharts

I have a highstocks multiseries chart and i want to show zones on one of the series. I have tried the example here:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.zones

but for some reason my zones show up with very translucent colors even though i have specified solid colors. Anybody face this situation?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw0Jj.png)

Comment: What are your settings?  It looks like you have a dash style on that line.

Comment: please provide some example to help us analyze your problem.

Comment: $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
   chart: {
    height: 600,
    zoomType: 'x'
   },
   series : [
    {
     name : 'series1',
                    data : seriesarray,
                    id: 'series1',
                    color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
            
                    yAxis:1,
                    dashStyle: 'solid',
                    zoneAxis: 'x',
                    zones:zones}]});
where zones is an array with around 100 items each in this format with value being a unix time stamp:{value:1455884713000, color:'#c2c2c2',dashStyle: 'solid', fillColor:'#c2c2c2'}

Comment: I am still unable to see where the problem is - http://jsfiddle.net/wygknLas/ Maybe you could post a JSFiddle showing the problem? Maybe there is some error in your data?

Comment: Turns out the issue was the dates in zones array had to be converted to utc format. http://jsfiddle.net/k72ff5kn/1/